# How to analyses sensitivity for understanding which variables are the most effect on the predictive model

Tags: random-forest, importance, sensitivity-analysis

I have a dataset with 150 observations. The dataset has 9 input parameters and 1 output parameter. I have built a predictive model (Random Forest) using the dataset. And now, I want to know that which variables are the most effect on the constructed predictive model. How can I do?
P/s: Please help me with an example because I am a newbie in R.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That doesn't help us without knowing the distribution of the outcome variable being predicted.  If discrete, need to know the entire set of cell frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

As you used RF to build you model, you can use a sensitivity measure (also called importance measure) which comes (almost) for free when you build the Random Forest: **mean decrease in accuracy** (also called permutation accuracy importance). As @Frank Harrell said, it is better to estimate a few times the random forest training to have multiple importance measure and have a better idea of their true importance.

See the paper of [Strobl et al. (2007)](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-8-25) for more details about the method.

Dependending on the library you used for your RF estimation, you could have it already computed or you may have to recompute it yourself.

In R, `RandomForest` and `cforest` packages provide it. In Python, `scikit-learn` does it too (`feature_importances_` parameter). Same in `Mllib`.
**If using R, use `cforest` without bootstrap, as advised in Strobl et al.**

Note also that you can still apply any classical [Sensitivity Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis) tool provided your problem is a regression (and not a classification). See HSIC indices, for example: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00903283/document and https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sensitivity/versions/1.14.0/topics/sensiHSIC

Comment: Thank you so much. I am using R. Have a way of calculating the sensitivity analysis?

Comment: What is the distribution of the outcome variable?  If it's binary what are the cell frequencies?  With a binary variable and a small sample size you are likely to have a lot of volatility in the random forest.

Comment: If I use another algorithm, which way to know sensitivity?

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced that with random forest the importance measures are stable.  Use the bootstrap to repeat the entire process and compute the importance measures a couple of hundred times, and show the variability in importance measures for each specific predictor.  You can use this also to compute 0.95 confidence limits on the importance ranking of each predictor.  If those confidence intervals are wide, you really can't know much about predictor importance.

Comment: I would also advise to repeat the importance measure with RF (will add it to my answer). For the stability, see this interesting study: https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-8-25

Comment: Could you make clearly? And if I have another predictive model, which way to know that?